# Unable to add ReactJS.NET on NetCore 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core-2.0

Im trying to add ReactJS.NET on NetCore2. I will use the net core app to retrieve some json information through a token and stuff like that.

I've encountered lots of problems with it (even if i followed the tutorials regarding its implementation).

At the moment i am getting an error such as `React.Exceptions.ReactScriptLoadException: Error while loading "~/React/main.js": SyntaxError: Module import or export statement unexpected here`

I have no idea why that is happening, but i do have a few questions (excepting how to fix the issue).

At the moment i have my react source in -> wwwwroot/React/Components. That folder also contains a "main.js" which i want to use to load my app. 
Is there a way that i could add the source behind wwwroot (not accessible to the user) since webpack already builds a file in wwwroot/dist/bundle.js ?

Also...anyone got any article/tutorial on how i can add watch to NetCore2 ? I literally forgot how to do it...

And regarding my problem here are my configs ->

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // This is our entry point containing the code 
    // required to perform server-side rendering.
    entry: './wwwroot/React/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        // Transform .jsx files.
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    "presets": [
                        "@babel/preset-react",
                        "@babel/preset-env"
                    ],
                    "plugins": [
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
                    ]
                },

            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        // Ensure we can deal with .js and .jsx and require files.
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    // Set mode for development, production or none.
    mode: 'none'
};
```

`Startup.cs`

```
        app.UseReact(config =>
        {
            config
                .SetLoadReact(true)
                .SetLoadBabel(true)
                .AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/dist/bundle.js")
                .AddScript("~/React/main.js");
        });
        services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName)
                .AddChakraCore();
        services.AddReact();
```

`main.js` - The one that throws the error - I added the IF because at some point i got an error such as "document is not defined"

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import App from './Components/App';


if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
}
```

And finally my view `ReactTest.cshtml`

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ReactTest";
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="true"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="true"></script>



@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
@Html.React("App", new { initialComments = Model.SPOResponse })
<h2>ReactTest</h2>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Any tips on how i could clean this up a bit/better configure it?

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I managed to clean up the code a bit by following this sample -> https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/tree/master/src/React.Sample.Webpack.CoreMvc

However...no i am having another problem. 
`React.Exceptions.ReactServerRenderingException: Error while rendering "RootComponent" to "react_0HLI7923A7GRL": Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

My main.js looks like this ->

```
require('expose-loader?React!react');
require('expose-loader?ReactDOM!react-dom');
require('expose-loader?ReactDOMServer!react-dom/server');

require('expose-loader?RootComponent!./App.jsx');
```

and my view has changed to this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="true"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="true"></script>


@Html.React("RootComponent", new { initialComments = Model.SPOResponse })
<script src="~/dist/bundle.js"></script>
@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

If i try to directly add my App.jsx content into my main.js i get an error telling me that i need a loader for that kind of content, even tho my webpack.config.js does contain `loader: 'babel-loader'`